# QGIS server 2.6.1 upgrade to 2.8.1 error

Tags: qgis, server, qgis-2.6, qgis-2.8

I plan on upgrading QGIS server from 2.6.1 to 2.8.1. At the time of 2.6.1 is used, however, to 2.8.1 found the map service can not be used, the emergence of internal server error 500.
`C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin\qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe - FastCGI Process unexpectedly quits`

I will qgis server as a fcgi module placed on iis, rather than on Apache. When I use QGIS 2.6.1 version, my service request is normal. this is the way my request:

http: //localhost/qgis_mapserv.slg SERVICE = WFS & version = 1.0.0 & request = getfeature & map = C:? /gis/zhongguo.qgs&typename=zhongguo
This is my request to return an error

Modules
FastCgiModule

Notification
ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler
qgisserver

Error Codes
0x00000001

Seems to be the application initialization error

Who can help me?

Comment: Welcome! From your link I understand that yo are using 64 bit windows. Could you please provide more information about how you access the server? Some more detail always makes it easier to answer a question. Also could you make it clear to us if you are actually trying to run two QGIS server instances at the same time? Your text is a bit unclear on this matte.r

Comment: Since apache is not in OSGEO4W for 64 bit, I suggest to run a complete 32bit linup to get qgis server running.

Comment: First of all thank you for giving me timely comment. I will qgis server as a fcgi module placed on iis, rather than on Apache. When I use QGIS 2.6.1 version, my service request is normal. this is the way my request:

Comment: http: //localhost/qgis_mapserv.slg SERVICE = WFS & version = 1.0.0 & request = getfeature & map = C:? /gis/zhongguo.qgs&typename=zhongguo
This is my request to return an error

Modules
FastCgiModule

Notification
ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler
qgisserver
Error Codes
0x00000001
Seems to be the application initialization error